# How to save an HTML5 canvas to a png

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to have a canvas be saved as an image so it can be put somewhere else on the website as an  tag.
I have seen approaches like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
document.write('<img src="'+strDataURI+'"/>');
```

But I am not sure how to implement it. I also would like a copy of the image to be saved as an actual file on the server as well but I am not sure where to start.

When I implement the above code, I put it at the bottom of my canvas script like such:

```
var finish = document.getElementID('finish');
finish.onclick = function() {

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
};
```

But I don't know how to actually reference the image.
A little help for noob is all I need.

Comment: He wants the user to download the file. I want to just display it and download it to the server. @JeremyJStarcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the frontside here's a full working example only showing a red background.
http://jsfiddle.net/gramhwkg/

```
// create a canvas
// If the canvas is already a dom element
//var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

// otherwise you'd rather do
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

// Then set a width/height grab its context.
canvas.width = 900;
canvas.height = 400;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// ... And do plenty of nice stuff with it.
// I'll just draw it Red.
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,900,400);

// When you want it to appear elsewhere.
var data = canvas.toDataURL();
var picture = document.getElementById("my-picture");
picture.innerHTML = '<img src="' + data + '"/>' ;
```

The backend part is not much harder. Just POST to php the same image data variable and handle it that way :

```
$canvas = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '' , $value['picture']));
file_put_contents('my_custom_path/my_custom_filename.png', $canvas);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Also I don't really use php so how would I go about implementing what you gave me? @JulienGarcia

Comment: Could you please open a new question for that and link it from here ? I can share more code with you.